# Tic Tac Toe game: I'm very confused why my code does not run when the user inputs one of the positional variables

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

For some reason, I cannot use a variable to define a space within this certain subset of the function

```
from turtle import *
john = Turtle()


def naughts(nposition):
    john.penup()
    john.goto(nposition)
    john.right(90)
    john.forward(120)
    john.left(90)
    john.pendown()
    john.circle(120)
    
def crosses(cposition):
    john.penup()
    john.goto(cposition)
    john.pendown()
    john.left(45)
    for x in range(4):
        john.forward(150)
        john.backward(150)
        john.left(90)
    john.right(45)


def main():
    
    pos1= (-400, 400)
    pos2= (0, 400)
    pos3= (400, 400)
    pos4= (-400, 0)
    pos5= (0, 0)
    pos6= (400, 0)
    pos7= -400, -400
    pos8= 0, -400
    pos9= 400, -400
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(-200, -600)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.left(90)
    john.forward(1200)
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(200, -600)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.forward(1200)
    john.left(90)
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(600, -200)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.forward(1200)
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(600,200)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.forward(1200)
    
    for turns in range(5):
        
        dake = input("Naughts, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
        
        naughts(dake)
        ecks = input("Crosses, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
        crosses(ecks)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With the variables at the very end, it returns

"TypeError: Vec2D.**new**() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given", and I'm unsure why.

I have tried to input the positional variables by themselves, which has worked.

Comment: The result of `input()` is a string. It's not automatically converted to the corresponding variable value.

Comment: Instead of separate variables, use a dictionary named `pos` whose keys are the position names. Then you can use `pos[dake]` to get the corresponding coordinates.

Comment: Hello, I'm rather new to coding, how would I go about creating a dictionary?

Comment: I would recommend searching up an online tutorial on how to do python, to get started. To make a dictionary, you just do this: `pos = {}`, and to add new elements to it, you would simply do this: `pos[dake] = value`. Try this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/?ref=header_search), it covers everything, including dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
john = Turtle()
POSITIONS = {"pos1":(-400, 400),
    "pos2": (0, 400),
    "pos3": (400, 400),
    "pos4": (-400, 0),
    "pos5":(0, 0),
    "pos6": (400, 0),
    "pos7": (-400, -400),
    "pos8": (0, -400),
    "pos9": (400, -400)}
john.speed(0) ## makes john very fast
def naughts(nposition):
    john.penup()
    john.goto(nposition)
    john.right(90)
    john.forward(120)
    john.left(90)
    john.pendown()
    john.circle(120)
    
def crosses(cposition):
    john.penup()
    john.goto(cposition)
    john.pendown()
    john.left(45)
    for x in range(4):
        john.forward(150)
        john.backward(150)
        john.left(90)
    john.right(45)


def main():
    john.penup()
    john.goto(-200, -600)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.left(90)
    john.forward(1200)
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(200, -600)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.forward(1200)
    john.left(90)
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(600, -200)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.forward(1200)
    
    john.penup()
    john.goto(600,200)
    john.pendown()
    
    john.forward(1200)
    
    for turns in range(5):
        
        dake = input("Naughts, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
        dake = POSITIONS[dake]
        naughts(dake)
        ecks = input("Crosses, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
        ecks = POSITIONS[ecks]
        crosses(ecks)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This fixes the problem you were having. What I did was make a dictionary containing the coordinates of the moves, and assigned the pos1, pos2... as keys so when the user enters the keys, `POSITIONS[dake]` returns the coordinates of the `dake` input.

The error was caused because `input()` returns a string, and parsing a string into the `.goto()` attribute caused a Typerror.

Now onto win detection...

Answer (score 0):

The trouble you face is that you need pixel positions which are pairs of integer values, but the user input delivers a string instead.

Let's make it easy for the start and create a list `lstPos` of defined positions which can be used to turn inputs like `1`, `2`, ... ,`9` into appropriate coordinates for the turtle to start drawing.

The code below tries to achieve proper function with as less changes to the original code as possible. Notice that in Python list indices start with 0, so a list with 9 items has indices from 0 to 8 (the reason for the `-1` in the specification of the index). The `int(nposition)` expression makes an integer out of a by user input string.

The code below fixes with small changes to the original code the issue of requesting 10 input values instead of only 9 possible asking for the tenth input in order to quit and close the turtle window.

Notice that the positions and the list of positions are not defined within the `main` function as it is the case in your original code. This makes the positions and the list of positions global values instead of local within the the `main()` function. Global values can then be easily accessed within the `naughts(nposition)` and `crosses(nposition)` functions.

```
from turtle import *
john = Turtle()

pos1= (-400, 400)
pos2= (0, 400)
pos3= (400, 400)
pos4= (-400, 0)
pos5= (0, 0)
pos6= (400, 0)
pos7= (-400, -400)
pos8= (0, -400)
pos9= (400, -400)
lstPos=[pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9]

def naughts(nposition):
    john.penup()
    john.goto(lstPos[int(nposition)-1])
    john.right(90)
    john.forward(120)
    john.left(90)
    john.pendown()
    john.circle(120)
    
def crosses(cposition):
    john.penup()
    john.goto(lstPos[int(cposition)-1])
    john.pendown()
    john.left(45)
    for x in range(4):
        john.forward(150)
        john.backward(150)
        john.left(90)
    john.right(45)

def main():
    john.penup()
    john.goto(-200, -600)
    john.pendown()
    john.left(90)
    john.forward(1200)
    john.penup()
    john.goto(200, -600)
    john.pendown()
    john.forward(1200)
    john.left(90)
    john.penup()
    john.goto(600, -200)
    john.pendown()
    john.forward(1200)
    john.penup()
    john.goto(600,200)
    john.pendown()
    john.forward(1200)
    
    for turns in range(4):
        dake = input("Naughts, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
        naughts(dake)
        ecks = input("Crosses, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
        crosses(ecks)

    dake = input("Naughts, please choose pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9: ")
    naughts(dake)
    input("Enter to exit/quit")
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```